# Can't Run Beacause No Spec file found Cypress

Tags: cypress

I am using Cypress version 9.0.0 and I have created Product1 and Product2 in my integration folder.I am using headless mode to run testcases using command -

`./node_modules/.bin/cypress run --spec cypress/integration/Product2/testcases/Login.spec.js`

my Directory structure is like:

```
cypress/
   fixture/
   integration/
   Product1/
     testcases/
       Login.spec.js
       testlist   --->testlist contain fileName ex:Login.spec.js
     usecases/
     testlist     ---->testlist contain folderName ex:testcases usecases
     constant.js
   Product2/
     testcases/
       Login.spec.js
       testlist     ---->testlist contain fileName ex:Login.spec.js
     usecases/
     testlist       ---->testlist contain folderName ex:testcases usecases
     constant.js
```

getting error as-
Can't run because no spec files were found
We searched for specs matching this glob pattern:

> /root/temp/abc/UI/cypress/integration/Product2/testcases/Login.spec.js

but if i used for Product1 ,
command

> /root/temp/abc/UI/cypress/integration/Product1/testcases/Login.spec.js

it Works fine and testcase run successfully.

I have Tried possibilities,

1. Changed in "specPattern":"cypress/integration/**/*.js" in cypress.json
2. Added testlist in integration which contain Product1 Product2
3. Tried [github Discussion](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/20734)
4. used
   `npx cypress run --config integrationFolder=cypress/integation/Product2/testcases/Login.spec.js`
   after this,all testcases run for Product1

Answer (score 2):

The Product1 and Product2 folders are shown at the same level as `cypress/integration`, so you can't get to them with `specPattern: 'cypress/integration/**/*.js'` - that will preclude those folder.

If you made a mistake in the folder diagram, then your simplest option is to change `specPattern` to an array

```js
{
  ...
  specPattern: [
    'cypress/integration/**/*.js',   // entry for specs under integration
    '**/Product1/**/*.js',           // specs under Product1
    '**/Product2/**/*.js',           // specs under Product2
  ]
}
```